# How to download a file over HTTP with AJAX?

Tags: http, jquery, download

I want to download a file from a server. The server part is working correctly.

Im using the following code:

```
$("#download-button").click(function() {
    alert("starting download");
    $.ajax({
        url:'download/myfile.txt'
    });
});
```

I get the alert (of course), but not the download.

However, when I manually go to `http://srv/download/myfile.txt`, i get the file downloaded.

What am I doing wrong in the AJAX call?

Comment: Missing `);` after the `$.ajax()` function. It still won't do anything, you can't initiate a download with Ajax (and why would you want to?)

Comment: The missing `);` was because it's an example code. The user clicks a button, the server is creating a file, and when it's created (can be a minute later), it must download it.

Comment: at the closer : too localized??? This question is almost too general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax should not be used to download files. Use instead [document.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.location)

```
// Set the value of the location object 
document.location = 'download/myfile.txt';
```